# Generalization of a property Of $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, simple-groups

Let $H$ and $K$ be two proper non-trivial subgroups of the 
alternating group $A_5$ and $\langle H,K\rangle < A_5$.
We can show that there exists a maximal subgroup $M$ of $A_5$ 
such that $H\not\leq M$ and $K\not\leq M$.
To see this let $\Omega:=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ 
and ${\rm Supp}_{\Omega}(H):=
\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \omega^{h}\neq \omega,$ for some $h\in H\}$. 
Since $|{\rm Supp}_{\Omega}(H)|\geq 3$ and $|{\rm Supp}_{\Omega}(K)|\geq 3$,
 ${\rm Supp}_{\Omega}(H)\cap {\rm Supp}_{\Omega}(K)\neq\emptyset$. 
Suppose that $l\in {\rm Supp}_{\Omega}(H)\cap {\rm Supp}_{\Omega}(K)$. 
Thus $H\not\leq {\rm stab}_{A_5}(l)$ and $K\not\leq {\rm stab}_{A_5}(l)$ and ${\rm stab}_{A_5}(l)$, 
which denotes the stabilizer of $l$ in $A_5$, is a maximal subgroup of $A_5$.

By  a GAP code I could see that this property is true for $A_6$ and $A_7$.
(Also it is true for $S_5$, $S_6$ and $M_{10}$).

Could we generalize this property to $A_n; n\geq 5$?

(If one of the subgroups $H$ or $K$ is transitive this property is true,
but I have no idea, when $H$ and $K$ are both intransitive).

Any answer or idea will be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there exists $l$ in the supports of both $H$ and $K$, then you can choose $M={\rm Stab}_{A_5}(l)$.

Otherwise, let $l$ be in the support of $H$ but not of $K$, and let $m$ be in the support of $K$ but not of $H$, and choose $M = {\rm Stab}_{A_5}(\{l,m\})$.

Comment: Dear prof.Holt, Thank you very much! Nice answer as always. According to your answer it seems to me this property also holds for $S_n; n\geq 4$ and any $n-$transitive group $G$, where $n\geq 4$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes the argument works for any $2$-transitive group.  It would be interesting to know if it the result is true for all finite nonabelian simple groups, for example, but I haven't had time to think any more about it.

Comment: Dear professor Holt, again thanks a lot for your nice answer!